# Moving Visual Studio to different location

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 in my C drive. Is any way I can move it to a different drive without affecting anything? If so, will I be able to install additional packages in the new drive?

Comment: Uninstall and Re-install.

Comment: It always installs in C-Drive, even if I select another location

Comment: Look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e7160ef-505e-4c48-a1aa-78e778c13ee0/install-visual-studio-2017-in-d-drive?forum=vssetup)